# Unmarshalled object is null if namespace prefix is not set

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have the following XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:x="MY_NAMESPACE"
           targetNamespace="MY_NAMESPACE">

    <xs:element name="response" type="x:responseType"/>

    <xs:complexType name="responseType">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="param" type="x:responseParam"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="responseParam">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

I use it to generate JAXB classes for unmarshalling a payload like the following:

```
<x:response xmlns:x="MY_NAMESPACE">
<param>
<value>OK</value>
</param>
</x:response>
```

via `getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive` in Spring. Problem is, I also want to unmarshal payloads without the namespace prefix, like this:

```
<response xmlns="MY_NAMESPACE">
<param>
<value>OK</value>
</param>
</response>
```

In this case, the `response` tag is parsed correctly, but the object reference representing `param` is always null. How can I edit my XSD to make things work? I already tried setting `elementFormDefault="qualified"` in the schema, or even `form="qualified"` on the `param` element.

Additional info that comes to mind (I might edit and add more depending on comments):

- The unmarshaller is a `Jaxb2Marshaller`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The XML documents**

I think you probably know this, but removing that namespace prefix affects the entire document (because the 'param' and 'value' tags do not have any prefix and therefore inherit the default namespace binding). Becauses of  this, in the first document the root tag 'response' is in namespace 'MY_NAMESPACE' and the other tags do not have any namespace. In the second document, all of the tags are in namespace 'MY_NAMESPACE'.

**The XML Schema**

The elementFormDefault attribute defaults to 'unqualified' so your schema should match the first document and reject the second. Your experiments confirm this. 
If you set elementFormDefault to 'qualified' then it will reject the first document and match the second one.
There is no value of elementFormDefault that will make the XSD match both XML documents. The namespace is an integral part of the identity of the element.

**Possible solution**

If you are determined to construct an XSD that matches both documents then it could be done as follows:

- explicitly set elementFormDefault to 'unqualified' (optional, but you're about to rely on that setting)b
- wrap the current (globally-declared) contents of responseType in a choice group
- add a second branch in the choice group containing a *local* declaration of element 'param' and all of its descendants. Because those are locally declared, they will be in noTargetNamespace.

This is not a general solution to the problem of making JAXB ignore namespaces, and I don't think you will find one (although I'm happy to be corrected by somebody who knows more than I do about JAXB).

Having said all of the above...I think you are probably solving the wrong problem. The JAXB standard is based on XML Schema. An XSD is not meant to tolerate the wrong namespaces. The second XML document is therefore invalid, and should be corrected by whoever is generating it.